# R Studio continually crashes when using a reactive element

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, ggvis

I am learning ggvis and shiny for the first time and the code I've written is causing R studio to crash when I use the slider. I am getting quite a few warning while it runs, but searching for answers hasn't been fruitful.

Error log from the console:

> > shiny::runApp('rworking/mtcars')
> >     Loading required package: shiny
> >     Warning: package ‘shiny’ was built under R version 3.4.2
> >
> > Listening on http://127.0.0.1:7789
> >     Warning: package ‘ggvis’ was built under R version 3.4.2
> >     The ggvis API is currently rapidly evolving. We strongly recommend that you do not rely on this for production, but feel free to explore. If you encounter a clear bug, please file a minimal reproducible example at https://github.com/rstudio/ggvis/issues. For questions and other discussion, please use https://groups.google.com/group/ggvis.
> >     Warning: package ‘dplyr’ was built under R version 3.4.2
> >
> > Attaching package: ‘dplyr’
> >
> > The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:
> >
> > filter, lag
> >
> > The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:
> >
> > intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
> >
> > Warning in bind_rows_(x, .id) :
> >       Unequal factor levels: coercing to character
> >     Warning in bind_rows_(x, .id) :
> >       binding character and factor vector, coercing into character vector
> >     Warning in bind_rows_(x, .id) :
> >       binding character and factor vector, coercing into character vector
> >     Warning in bind_rows_(x, .id) :
> >       binding character and factor vector, coercing into character vector
> >     Warning in bind_rows_(x, .id) :
> >       Unequal factor levels: coercing to character
> >     Warning in bind_rows_(x, .id) :
> >       binding character and factor vector, coercing into character vector
> >     Warning in bind_rows_(x, .id) :
> >       binding character and factor vector, coercing into character vector
> >     Warning in bind_rows_(x, .id) :
> >       binding character and factor vector, coercing into character vector
> >     Warning in bind_rows_(x, .id) :
> >       Unequal factor levels: coercing to character
> >     Warning in bind_rows_(x, .id) :
> >       binding character and factor vector, coercing into character vector
> >     Warning in bind_rows_(x, .id) :
> >       binding character and factor vector, coercing into character vector
> >     Warning in bind_rows_(x, .id) :
> >       binding character and factor vector, coercing into character vector
> >     Warning in simpleLoess(y, x, w, span, degree = degree, parametric = parametric,  :
> >       span too small.   fewer data values than degrees of freedom.
> >     Warning in simpleLoess(y, x, w, span, degree = degree, parametric = parametric,  :
> >       pseudoinverse used at 27.267
> >     Warning in simpleLoess(y, x, w, span, degree = degree, parametric = parametric,  :
> >       neighborhood radius 3.133
> >     Warning in simpleLoess(y, x, w, span, degree = degree, parametric = parametric,  :
> >       reciprocal condition number  0
> >     Warning in simpleLoess(y, x, w, span, degree = degree, parametric = parametric,  :
> >       There are other near singularities as well. 12.482
> >     Warning in bind_rows_(x, .id) :
> >       Unequal factor levels: coercing to character
> >     Warning in bind_rows_(x, .id) :
> >       binding character and factor vector, coercing into character vector
> >     Warning in bind_rows_(x, .id) :
> >       binding character and factor vector, coercing into character vector
> >     Warning in bind_rows_(x, .id) :
> >       binding character and factor vector, coercing into character vector
> >     Warning in bind_rows_(x, .id) :
> >       Unequal factor levels: coercing to character
> >     Warning in bind_rows_(x, .id) :
> >       binding character and factor vector, coercing into character vector
> >     Warning in bind_rows_(x, .id) :
> >       binding character and factor vector, coercing into character vector
> >     Warning in bind_rows_(x, .id) :
> >       binding character and factor vector, coercing into character vector
> >     Warning in simpleLoess(y, x, w, span, degree = degree, parametric = parametric,  :
> >       span too small.   fewer data values than degrees of freedom.
> >     Warning in simpleLoess(y, x, w, span, degree = degree, parametric = parametric,  :
> >       pseudoinverse used at 19.189
> >     Warning in simpleLoess(y, x, w, span, degree = degree, parametric = parametric,  :
> >       neighborhood radius 1.811
> >     Warning in simpleLoess(y, x, w, span, degree = degree, parametric = parametric,  :
> >       reciprocal condition number  0
> >     Warning in simpleLoess(y, x, w, span, degree = degree, parametric = parametric,  :
> >       There are other near singularities as well. 0.16892
> >     Error: span is too small
> >     Warning: Error in UseMethod: no applicable method for 'apply_props' applied to an object of class "function"
> >     Stack trace (innermost first):
> >         71: apply_props
> >         70: 
> >         59: data_reactive
> >         58: as.vega
> >         57: session$sendCustomMessage
> >         56: observerFunc
> >          1: shiny::runApp
> >     Warning: Error in UseMethod: no applicable method for 'apply_props' applied to an object of class "function"
> >     Stack trace (innermost first):
> >         59: 
> >         58: stop
> >         57: data_table[[name]]
> >         56: observerFunc
> >          1: shiny::runApp
> >     ERROR: [on_request_read] connection reset by peer

**Server.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(ggvis)
library(dplyr)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {


  mtcars %>%
    group_by(cyl) %>%
    ggvis(~mpg, ~disp, fill = ~factor(cyl)) %>%
    filter(mpg > eval(input_slider(10, 35, 10))) %>%  # this is the trick
    layer_points() %>%
    layer_smooths() %>%
    scale_numeric("x", domain = c(10, 35)) %>%  # keep axis stable
    scale_numeric("y", domain = c(0, 500)) %>%  # same
    bind_shiny("p", "p_ui") 
})
```

**ui.R**

```
library(ggvis)
library(shiny)

shinyUI(bootstrapPage(
  wellPanel(
    uiOutput("p_ui"),
    ggvisOutput("p"),
    HTML("Comparing cars by disp and mpg")
  )))
```

Comment: What are errors and warnings? Are there any crash logs?

Comment: I added what appears in the console when I run the program

Comment: There are couple of errors involving `UseMethod`, maybe check that?

Comment: When I remove "layer_smooths()" the errors that causes the crashing go away. I'm wondering why this only happens with layer_smooths

Comment: Try http://community.rstudio.com/ for weird RStudio problems that seem to be no fault of your programming.